# Using drag events to move scroll bar in Sencha Touch 2.0

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have an app I have deployed to the iOS and Android stores. Now I am taking the same thing and building a version that also works on the desktop in Chrome/Safari. For this I used the code in this thread

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?110792-Add-support-for-mouse-scrolling-(for-development)&p=927483#post927483

to fix the scrolling and now need to figure out how to fix the scroll bar to support dragging and dropping. Any pointers on how this could be accomplished - am going to try to figure it out, but if someone has done it before that would help.

I initially tried to go down the ExtJS path for the desktop app, but found that there are enough differences between the two frameworks that it becomes pretty expensive to develop and maintain, so want to put out a V1 out there quickly and then figure out how to handle this in the long term if I have enough interest to put out one for IE and FireFox - and with desktop based controls.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the scroll bar in sencha touch will be hide by default and fade out after you finish dragging a long list or a panel... If you want to make your scroll bar always visible you can set this in your css or scss file:

```
.x-tabpanel .x-scroll-indicator {
    opacity: 0.5 !important; 
    z-index: 0; // Make scroll bar draggable
}
```

Maybe I'm understand your question wrongly but hope it helps :)

Comment: This I have already done this to show the scroll bars. I need to support people who have to click on the scroll bar and drag it to scroll - windows laptops without mouse, for that I need to support drag and drop support.

Comment: I don't get you because when the school bar is visible, the bar is already support drag and drop?

Comment: This does not work for me, when I show the scroll bar using the css above, the scroll bar shows up. But I am not able to drag and drop this as it does not move unless I use the mousewheel. Can you please tell me how you see the ability to drag and drop or point me to how this could be done.

Comment: I just realize that your requirement is for desktop version which means that when you drag the scroll bar it will obviously opposite direction as compare when you drag the scroll bar on the mobile device. I find a way to drag the scrollbar but obviously it will follow the mobile way not for desktop and you need to remember that sencha touch will always means for mobile application.

Comment: That is also OK, I am just not able to drag at all. Do you know what I need to do to fix it so dragging works.

Comment: Actually this is a trick so you can add z-index: 0 to your scroll bar to make it works. See my edit :)

Comment: Yes that did the trick. The complexity of this on Windows of the scrolling being the opposite of how the bar goes and opposite of the Mac and devices is complexity I have to figure out how to handle now.